# Database backup using sql management studio 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-backup

I want to retrieve a script for a database that will include operations of creating database, creating tables, and insert all data. How can I achieve this using management studio 2008 please.

I have tried the generate script option , but that seems to create only table structure, doesn't create database or doesn't insert data either.

Either

Comment: If you are using a GUI, it is most definitely not programming.

Comment: @leppie: absolutely true, but most programmers have to get their hands dirty with databases. :) I'd put this in the same bracket as asking how to get rid of warnings in visual studio

Answer (score 3):

There are to separate steps:

1. Use the **Script Database as / CREATE To / ...** operation to generate *script for the database*.
2. Use the **Tasks / Generate Scripts...** operation to generate *script for the objects inside the database*.
   Make sure to set the **Script Data** option to **True** to generate INSERT statements along with tables structure.

   [image]

Comment: hi thanks, I got how to extract data to script. Now, can you please tell me, how can I set option so that the script generates the db if not exist? Currently it has query with "USE DBName" , but it won't work if the database doesn't exist on the server.

Comment: @Rana Use `IF DB_ID('database_name') IS NULL` to determine if the database is missing and use the script generated with **Script Database as / CREATE To / ...** to create with.

Comment: so, there is not direct option without doing it manually in the sql script? Anyway, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Took me a while to find the start point for this. For anyone else: Select your database in the object explorer. - Right Click and select - Tasks - Generate Scripts to bring up the wizard as described above.